# A smile of contentment

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, phrases

Would you be so kind as to let me know which phrasing below sounds more natural and constructionally more appealing in English?

> - I never forget the moment when he came up to me .......... and said: "thank you for all your efforts during the whole that time."

**a. wearing a smile of contentment** [this choice seems to me a little poetic.] 
**b. having a smile of contentment** [the most natural one to my year.] 
**c. giving me a smile of contentment** [sounds a bit odd to me.]

I have no idea, how to phrase this segment elegantly and idiomatically in English.

Comment: **during the whole that time** is wrong.  But either opt for **a.** or use **with a smile...**

Comment: a contented smile is better and shorter.

Answer (score 1):

By *idiomatically and elegantly*, I think you should go with **a**